# Android HTML5 video plays but not visible

Tags: android, html, video, webview, inline

I did a great deal of research trying to find out why html5 videos won't play correctly in my app. To be more specific the page loads fine, you can see the initial controls of the video player, but when you hit play you here the sound from the video but you can't see anything.

I'm using a webview to display it and using several online links for testing such as:

- http://videojs.com/
- http://broken-links.com/tests/video/

Here is my webview code:

```
String _location = "http://broken-links.com/tests/video/";
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.dsWebView);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); //chromeClient());        
wv.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);   
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);   
webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.setInitialScale(50); 
wv.loadUrl(_location);


private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{ 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    { 
        view.loadUrl(url); 
        return true;//false; 
    } 
}
```

I also changed my project so that it's for android 4.0 and above and set android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in my manifest file.

To also add, I did test both links in both my default browser on my htc one x and on the chrome beta browser and it plays perfectly on both. It's just my webview that doesn't work :(.

I'm basically trying to figure out what i'm missing to get the video to play correctly within my webview.

Thanks for any help in advance,

Fire

Comment: Are you sure the video isn't encoded with some kind of unrecognized codec?

Comment: What OS are you running? Is Flash installed on the device?

Comment: Android 4.0.3 and yes flash 11 is installed. I'm using AT&T's HTC one x to test.

Comment: but those links work in the default browser on the phone. It's only webview thats giving the issue :(

Comment: any other ideas? :( I'm still stuck

Comment: Try re-encoding it (or finding a video that works) in a format you _know_ is HTML5 compatible. Just to make sure that isn't the problem. It just sounds like a codec problem to me though I might be wrong.

Comment: Those are live websites that i'm testing. It's not my own videos. Do you have any links I could test?
Also if it was a codec issue, wouldn't it also NOT work on the phones browser?

Comment: Check this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13762699/4265546

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally! I figured out my issue. It was my intent filters in my manifest file. If I posted it someone probably would have been able to spot the issue faster, sorry for that.

```
<manifest>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
  <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true"/> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />          
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">              
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>             
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">              
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>
        </intent-filter>            
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">               
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>
        </intent-filter>            
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>
        </intent-filter>                              
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="myWebView"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"         
    ></activity>
</application>
```

I had to remove my intent filters that I added to launch my app from any file with ".test".
Basically removing this part and it started to work:

```
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">              
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>             
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">              
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>
        </intent-filter>            
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">               
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>
        </intent-filter>            
        <intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="Test File"
            android:priority="1">            
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.test"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Now my next issue is how can I launch my app from a .test file if it's causing my html5 to not work. (I figure I can remove the http filter, but I would like to click on a link on a webpage that downloads and opens my .test file.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why removing the intent filters solved the problem? I can't see why this would be related (I am coping with a similar issue only I don't have any intent filters like you've had).

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
wv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```