# Video is not Displaying in Webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview, html5-video

I have one Html Page, In this Html Page I am displaying one Video but this video is not displaying in my application's webview but displaying in Default Browser, so Please tell me what is the problem, below is my code and video and html file is stored into sdcard, sorry for my bad english communication.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webPage;
    Button next;
    String rootDir = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/iR-unzip/testbook/";
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();
    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webPage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webPage.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
        webPage.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webPage.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webPage.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webPage.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webPage.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webPage.loadUrl(rootDir + "/" + "chapter_1.html");
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.page_changer);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                webPage.loadUrl(rootDir + "/" + "chapter_2.html");
            }
        });

    }

    public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
                if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                    VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                    frame.removeView(video);
                    video.start();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Html Page:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>Chapter 1 for testBook</title>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 600px;margin: 0 auto;">
<div id="text"> 
<p><h4>WSDL for client access</h4>
A WSDL service description provides all the information that is required to use a web
service. The T320 version of Eclipse incorporates the Web Tools Platform (WTP),
which provides support for generating a client based on the information inside a
WSDL.
<h4>OU demo services</h4></h4>
<p>At the OU there is a small set of toy web services. These can be accessed using a
client in the same way as you tested the 'Hello' web service using Eclipse. In fact, one
of the web services hosted is a copy of the 'Hello' service.</p>
<img src="Caterpillar-Insect-Animal-Macro-HD-600x375.jpg" />

<p>Click on the 'Browse' button at the top of the box. This will take you to the dialogue box shown in Figure 11.</p>
<img src="images.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<h3>HTML5 Video : </h3>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line

```
  wb.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

with this one

```
  wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: Also, the manifest file needs to be updated like <application
android:hardwareAccelerated="true". Check this thread: https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414#gistcomment-572240