# Video not playing on android webview

Tags: android, html, video

I am working with an Android and PhoneGap application and am using the HTML5 video tag to play videos on my web page. When I play the video  is not visible and video is not playing itself. How can I play a HTML5 video on Android?

Code for the same given below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >


        <video id="video" autobuffer height="240" width="360" onclick="this.play();>
<source src="test.mp4">
<source src="test.mp4" type="video/webm">
<source src="test.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>

        <div id="msg"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

and the activity class onCreate method-->>

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS); 

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/html5videoEvents.html");      
}
```

Comment: check this link might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4990544/1602230

Comment: Refer this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video

Comment: @Sathish no its just a video.. What op needs is html5video in webview..

Comment: that link is not working for me.Actually I was trying play the video in webview through html5 .So please tell me any other solution

Comment: @rand Are you testing this application on which api version?

Comment: @Dipak I am testing it in emulator 4.1 and device is 4.0 and compiled code is in android 4.1

Comment: @rand In my application, the html5 video is playing on android 4.0.3 API version so please check your application on 4.0.3 API.

Comment: @Dipak can you please share your code for the same

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines before loading HTML content to your WebView.

```
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});
```

From the documentation:

> In order to support inline HTML5 video in your application, you need to have hardware acceleration turned on, and set a WebChromeClient. For full screen support, implementations of onShowCustomView(View, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback) and onHideCustomView() are required, getVideoLoadingProgressView() is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webPage;
    Button next;
    String rootDir = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/iR-unzip/testbook/";
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();
    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webPage = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webPage.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
        webPage.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webPage.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        //webPage.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webPage.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webPage.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        webPage.loadUrl(rootDir + "/" + "chapter_1.html");
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.page_changer);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                webPage.loadUrl(rootDir + "/" + "chapter_2.html");
            }
        });

    }

    public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
            if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;
                if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                    VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();
                    frame.removeView(video);
                    video.start();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for your code .can u please send me your html file where you mentioned the video file

Comment: @rand Please see html file on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085424/video-is-not-displaying-in-webview

Comment: thaknx for ur response so you are using sdcard but I was trying to load the html from assets/www folder.Do You hav any idea how to do that

Comment: Write asset path instead of sdcard path.

Comment: @ Dipak getting error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
while running in emulator 4.1..

Comment: @rand please post html file path here or update your question.

Comment: @ can you please give ur email ID so that  I can send the project itself via mail

Comment: @rand yes and please give me sometime.

Comment: @ Dipak thankx for your help.Did you find any outcome with that

Comment: @rand First store your html file and video in sdcard instead of asset folder and then check.

Comment: instead of storing in sdcard if I store html and video in asset folder then why not able to play

Comment: Use html code and java code from this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085424/video-is-not-displaying-in-webview

Comment: thankx playing from sdcards but not able to play from asset.I need to play from asset folder

Comment: @rand Sorry for that but i don't know about this.

Comment: can Any one help me for the same?

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Dude is it possible when we click on video than small frame popup which play video and when video finish our loaded web site again showup...i am using assets folder to store html and videos. any suggestion

Comment: MyWebChromeClient is never used :)